# How to create a String and Integer sequence in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, integer, sequence

**Aim**

The aim is to create a String and Integer sequence in Ruby, i.e., `hello0, hello1, hello2`. `hello` represents a String and the numbers: `1,2 and 3` are the integers.

**Attempt**

`seq=(0..3).to_a`

returns

`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`

**Question**

How to create a String and Integer sequence in Ruby?

Comment: Like this? `["hello"].product((0..3).to_a).map(&:join) #=> ["hello0", "hello1", "hello2", "hello3"]`

Comment: @engineersmnky Works. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't see any question there.

Comment: @sawa In my opinion it is completely clear what I want, but I have added a question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The aim is to create a text and integer sequence in Ruby, i.e., `hello0, hello1, hello2`

You can pass a block to [`Array::new`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
Array.new(3) { |i| "hello#{i}" }
#=> ["hello0", "hello1", "hello2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(0..3).to_a.map {|e| "hello#{e}" }
```